# Google Videos Flash Player

Tags: html, flash

I've been looking through the net for over an hour and I still can't find the way that sites like http://kissanime.com/ have their players set. Also, one more thing that is in my mind is how are they storing their videos and where? I couldn't think of anything. Sorry for giving you this question, but I couldn't think of anywhere else to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just store their video at their DNS server they rented of course .
When they are designing their webpage they just wrote something like src=(pathway to their flash video ) so this will link the webpage to their video . They have installed certain plugin in their server so that you can play the video.

Comment: Sounds fair enough, thanks! Will have to look more about it ^^